# ASP Classic - Checkbox multi-chosen but the first checking item won't do anything

Tags: asp-classic, vb6

My ASP program

```
wint = 30

For j= 1 To wint

      chk_stat = Trim(Request("chk_m" & j))

If chk_stat = "" then

      chk_stat = 0

Else

      chk_stat = 1

End If

If chk_stat = 1 Then

      DoSomethingHere

End If
```

`Next`

Html Tag

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_m<%=I%>">
```

where I from 1 to 30

I want to multiple check these boxes (amount=30) , but after checking, I find the first checkbox will not execute 'DoSomethingHere' program. But the second, third, and so on will be OK. So How can I modify my mistake, thank you!

Comment: your first checkbox is probably already checked from the start, so checking it doesnt change anything, and the event isnt fired

Comment: Why checkbox has its status in initial? I try this test, and the result is the first checked item always be null (Trim(Request("chk_m" & j) = "")
), so I can't do the next if expression. And the above item, I need to add "Next" for "For" loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `value` attribute for your `INPUT` element:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_m<%=I%>" value="1">
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it's not work. The first checkbox is always off whether I've checked it.

Comment: Can you post more code? Is the code in your question activated when you submit your form?